# Open up Notepad in Right-to-Left Reading Order mode by default

Tags: windows-10, notepad, right-to-left

Is there any way to change default text direction of Windows's Notepad (*not Notepad++*) to `RTL`? I mean I want to every time I open a file using Notepad, the `Right-to-Left Reading Order` get checked by default. I usually work with RTL text files.

*I'm using Windows 10 btw*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My hunch is that there is no way to do this. Notepad is generally unconfigurable and this is likely another example of that state of affairs.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to capture the registry to see if it can be configured, but it's not.

To be the workaround, you can use these hotkey to make the change easily.

Hotkey combo:

- to write text from Right to Left, try Ctrl + Right Shift
- to write    text from Left to Right, try Ctrl + Left Shift

Comment: I knew the hotkeys, my question is something else

Comment: Yep, I have tried to created some shortcut to do so, but failed. In my opinion, we can only use the hotkey just as workaround.